# MySQL - How to get the difference of all the rows in a column within a specific "id"?

Tags: mysql

For example, in this table:

```
n   id   num

1   10   100
2   11    60
3   10    20
4   10    20
5   11    10
```

How do I subtract all the values of num  (from top to bottom) with id = 10?

The first value of num in id=10 is subtracted to the 2nd value of num in id = 10 and the answer is subtracted to the third value of num in id = 10 (an so on and so forth if there are n numbers of num with the id =10)

It should display this:

```
difference of id = 10

50
```

Comment: Please explain how 60 and 50 are calculated.

Comment: the first value of num in id=10 is subtracted to the 2nd value of num in id = 10 and the answer is subtracted to the third value of num in id = 10 (an so on and so forth if there are n numbers of num with the id =10)

Comment: Edit your question with additional requirements and provide desired result

Comment: Ok. That makes no sense, and no reference to comments below either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code you need:

```
SELECT AA.ID, (num_duo-total_sum) as num_diff FROM 

(SELECT id, 2*num as num_duo, MIN(n) FROM t1 GROUP BY id ) AA LEFT JOIN 


(SELECT id, SUM(num) as total_sum FROM t1 GROUP BY id) BB ON BB.id = AA.id
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d4326/12/0)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to take the first value for the given id and then subtract subsequent values.  "first" is defined by the first column, `n`.

If so, then this might help:

```
select sum(case when t.n = f.firstn then num else - num end)
from table t cross join
     (select min(n) as firstn
      from table t
      where id = 10
     ) f
where id = 10;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d4326/14) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I'm getting an error with that code: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table t cross join
     (select min(n) as firstn
      from table t
      where ' at line 2 `

Comment: @shindonism . . . `table` is intended to be the table that has the data.  Your question doesn't specify the name of the table.

Comment: yes, realized that I forgot to put the name of the table so I just renamed my table to "table". And got that error

Comment: tried renaming it back again to another table name (and changed the table name in the code).. the error is gone but it returned `-10`